# Tree search in Clojure core.logic

Tags: clojure, tree, clojure-core.logic, tree-search

I've been puzzled by a modelisation problem for some time and I have to confess I have no idea how I could "properly" solve it in `core.logic`.

It is very easy to state: given a tree (acyclic unidirectional oriented graph) and a vertex in it, how do you use `core.logic` to define a goal which allow a lvar to be any reachable vertex from the given vertex?

I've started out with something as simple as possible:

```
(defrel vertex x)
(defrel child)
(def facts
  (pldb/db
    [vertex 'a]
    [vertex 'b] [child 'a 'b]
    [vertex 'c] [child 'b 'c]
    [vertex 'd] [child 'c 'd]))
```

Given this configuration, I aim at defining a goal which allows a lvar to take values in ['a 'b 'c 'd]. It's straightforward to get reachable vertices with "1 hop":

```
(defn reachableo
  [a]
  (fresh [q]
    (child a q)))
```

and you can add variables for 2 hops and so on but... can it be generalized? I've thought to define a list of lvar with something like

```
(let [vars (repeatedly lvar)]
  (map #(child (nth vars %) (nth vars (inc %)))
       (-> vars count dec range))
  (all
    ...))
```

but several attempts later, I must confess I'm not sure it's the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(pldb/db-rel vertex x)
(pldb/db-rel child parent child)
(def facts
  (pldb/db
    [vertex 'a]
    [vertex 'b] [child 'a 'b]
    [vertex 'c] [child 'b 'c]
    [vertex 'd] [child 'c 'd]))
```

The recursive goal:

```
(defn reachable° [from to]
  (l/fresh [v]
    (l/conde
      [(child from to)]
      [(child from v) (reachable° v to)])))
```

Testing

```
=> (pldb/with-db facts
     (vec (l/run* [to] (reachable° 'a to))))
[b c d]
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help!

Actually I got

```
(defn order-relationo
  "Abstract the general pattern of a order relation in a logic, relational way."
  [relation x y]
  (conde
   [(relation x y)]
   [(fresh [z]
      (relation x z)
      (order-relationo relation z y))]))

(def kino
  "A goal where the two inputs x and y share kinship: x is an ancestor of y and
  y a descandant of x."
  (partial order-relationo child))
```

I asked this question because it was a long time I hadn't practiced logic programming but now I feel it's coming again ^^

Anyway, thanks a lot for your answer which gives me an additional viewpoint.